# Xap packaging failed

Tags: windows-phone-7, xap

I do not manage to compile my project Windows phone 7 with a video of 80 Mb.
When I start the build, a OutOfMermoryException is generated …

*Xap packaging failed. Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.*

What is that somebody has already had this problem? I thought that the limit of size for the XAP was 400 Mb...

Thank for your help !

Comment: Hi Chris, A few questions come to mind.

How much RAM does your system have?

Have you tried compiling after rebooting and not loading other apps?

Do you have a spare hard disk that you could try a clean Win7 install on to rule out any OS corruption issues or side effects from other installed software/configuration?

Comment: Hi Mick,

I have 4 Gb of RAM, I have tried many times to reboot my machine but there is always the compilation error.
I use my machine only for the Windows Phone 7 development, so I think the problem isn't coming from other softwares...

In fact with a 80 mb video everything works find but with a 200 Mb video I have the error...
I haven't other launched applications.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Can you show the detailed output from the build/compilation attempt

Comment: Just a note: are you sure that including an 80 Mb video in a phone app is the right thing to do? I know I wouldn't bother installing such a large app.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a 'xap' is just a 'zip'  so as long as your 80mb video is not being complied into a dll you can just compile the xap > change the file extension to zip > unzip > add in your video > zip > change file extension to xap.